# Harmonic function vanishing at infinity is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function (i.e. $\Delta f = 0$) and suppose $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x) = 0$. Is it true that $f$ must be identically zero?

It seems the answer is *yes*, by an application of the maximum principle. Because $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x) = 0$, given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $R > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le \varepsilon$ whenever $|x| \ge R$. Take $\bar{\Omega} = \overline{B_{R}(0)}$ to be the closed ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin. Moreover, let $\Omega = \text{int} \bar{\Omega}$, which is open and nonemtpy. Then $f$ is harmonic on $\Omega$ and, by the maximum principle, it must have a maximum at $\partial \Omega$. This maximum is less or equal than $\varepsilon$ and, since the latter is arbitrary, it follows that $f = 0$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is totally right. It also follows from one of [Liouville's theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville's_theorem). Speaking of the latter. You may want to enjoy [Edward Nelson's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237279/nelsons-proof-of-liouvilles-theorem) proof of  it. The master uses no formulas.